# Using conduit with THHN

Tags: electrical, wiring, conduit

May I run THHN above ground under a house unprotected or is a conduit required for this? The wires consist of 3 4AWG wires with an 8AWG ground going from a 60A breaker at the (100A) service to a newly built garage via underground wiring from the garage in 1.25" schedule 40 PVC and then under the house, which is raised on piers.

Comment: Did you mean THHN?

Comment: Are you talking about some sort of crawlspace here, or the space under a house that's been mounted on piers?

Comment: dyslexic I am,...yes and yes to the space under house with piers

Answer (score 5):

Any time you are running bare conductors in a dwelling unit that are not part of a cable system such as NM or MC, then they must be run in a conduit. Once you get to the exterior of the unit you could transition to a Direct burial cable such as UF or you could continue in a conduit system.  The most common under ground conduit would be PVC and it could also be used under the house.

good luck

Special note: Most conductor insulation is multi rated but a straight THHN rating is not rated for wet locations it should also be labeled as THWN to be approved for buried circuits.

Answer (score 4):

Remember you need Schedule 80 PVC where the conduit approaches the surface or  in a place subject to potential damage. It is thicker pipe, but the joint surfaces are compatible with Sched 40. (it sacrifices inside diameter).

Single wires need to be inside a conduit or raceway *their entire run*. So no, you cannot direct-affix THHN wires.  You have several options:

- Run conduit the entire way. Feel free to switch to EMT once you are out of the earth; you will get less contact cement on your fingers and you won't need expansion joints. Bonus: EMT *is the ground path* so you don't need that #8 ground. (which is fine by the way).
- Install a junction box, and splice to a multi-conductor *cable* for the rest of the run.  This will require a Rather Large junction box, and Polaris connectors, and large entry hole, and large cable clamp for the cable - and the cost of all that might be worse than the EMT.
- The dreaded "cable in conduit" - run appropriate wet-rated cable the entire run, and go through the pain and suffering of cramming the cable through the conduit.  Not a fan of this one; fair chance it will overwhelm your DIY skills and force  you to pay an electrician a small fortune to pull the cable and finish the job (they won't *just* pull).

As an aside, your wet location needs **THWN** wires, but almost all THHN is dual-marked as both THHN and THWN-2.

### Some other gotchas:

For a 100A feeder to a subpanel, you need #3 copper (better: #1 aluminum).   Lots of people get tripped up by this*.  If you are married to #4, you are limited to 70A.

#include standard "Aluminum is the right stuff for feeder" speech.

#include standard "compute voltage drop based on practical load not breaker trip, and don't compute based on 3%" speech.

---

At an outbuilding, your subpanel will need a **shutoff switch**.  The cheapest way to get a shutoff switch is pick a subpanel that has a main breaker.  *You're not using it as a main breaker, capische?* So **don't match the main breaker to he feeder breaker**. It's *irrelevant* and will force poor panel choices, like a 4-space panel for 60A or 12-space for 100A.  You want more spaces than that -- really.

Spaces are dirt cheap when buying a panel.  The biggest cliche in home subpanels is spending $400 too much on wire, but saving $40 getting a too-small panel, promptly running out of spaces**, and having to spend another $100 replacing the panel.  You want enough breaker spaces that you *never run out*, because spaces are cheap before you install it, and expensive after.

---

---

*The reason this mistake happens is people drawing from a table intended for *service entrances*. This has been such an epidemic that the table has been removed from NEC.

** "circuits" don't count as "spaces", so a 12 space/24 circuit panel is in fact only 12 spaces.  24 relies on "double-stuff" breakers, which don't come in AFCI or GFCI, so such a panel is only 24 circuits in an imaginary world where those are not required.  Here on Earth it's a 12-circuit.

Comment: His feeder is 60A, BTW

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel for now, yes. But that choice of wire allows him headroom to swap in a 70A breaker at his discretion... my point is, not a 100A and a bump from 4 to 3 will give him 100A.

Comment: Noted, I was told as much by codes inspector, but have too many "expert friends" who I need to turn off. Thanks all.

Comment: how do I vote on this boards help ,4stars, if I knew how.

Comment: Code inspectors will tell you #4 for 100A @gchilton3, because that is allowed for "service" wire. i.e. *every load in the service goes down that wire*.  They're almost always dealing with that, so it's habit. They are thinking of 310.15b7 which applies to service and whole-service feeder, used to be a table and now is an 83% favorable derate.  The correct branch/subfeed table: 310.15b16 *using the 60C column <100A and 75C column >=100A*.  Which is a visual mess.

Comment: @gchilton3 voting is left edge of answers, arrows above and below the number.  You also have a check mark to select best answer.